# DPI conflict with i2C

Tags: i2c

I am getting following error, Kindly help.

I have tried understanding dtbo files, changing config also. still no luck.

I want to know, how i can assign gpio pins to i2C (picamera2)and DPI (4inch DPI having 40 gpio pin header set)

```
3.018388] pinctrl-bcm2835 fe200000.gplo: pin gpio2 already requested by fe804000.i2c: cannot claim for fe208000.dpi 

3.0185391 pinctri-bcm2835 fe200000.gpio: pin-2 (fe208000.dpi) status -22 

3.0186161 pinctrl-bcm2835 fc200000.gpio: could not request pin 2 (gpio2) from group gpio2 on deuice pinctrl-bcm2711 

3.018719] vc4_dpi fe2.00000.dpi: Error applying setting, reverse things back
```

Comment: I see on `https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html`, "On almost all models ... i2c0 (belongs) to VC, where it is used to control the camera" (ctrl f, i2c in the box, at 31 of 54 matches).  If the Header hat is using all 40 pins, you may be out of luck, check your header specs. The RPI4 has more i2c options, see /boot/overlays.

Answer (score 0):

You *typically* assign GPIO pins to I2C using the file `/boot/config.txt`. There is another file that explains the syntax and options of all the `dtoverlay` and `dtparam` configurations; it is located at `/boot/overlays/README`.

And please forgive me if this comes across as pedantic, but you should know that you cannot assign an I2C function to any pins at random. If you had bothered to let us know what model RPi you're using, we might have been able to offer more advice on your choices, but a good reference can be found at [The Raspberry Pi Pinout](https://pinout.xyz/#).

Finally, to avoid any potential issues, you should **enable** the I2C you plan on using via `raspi-config` (`sudo raspi-config` from the command line). This is option 3 in the menu: `Interface Options`.